# UISegmentControl filter Table View data JSON error

Tags: ios, json, uitableview

I'm trying to filter the data of my Table View which is calling a JSON-file and parses the data to the Table View. I'm getting some strange errors. Here's my code:

```
#import "FacebookViewController.h"
#import "RNBlurModalView.h"
#import "FacebookPost.h"
#import "TwitterPost.h"

#define CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH 320.0f
#define CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN 10.0f
#define FONT_SIZE 14.0f

@interface FacebookViewController ()
{
    NSInteger refreshIndex;
    NSArray *fbPost;
    NSArray *pic;
}

@end

@implementation FacebookViewController
@synthesize tweets;

- (void)refreshChannels:(id)sender {

    if (tweets.count == 0) return;

    // disable UI
    self.title = @"Updating...";
    self.navigationController.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    refreshIndex = 0;
}

- (void) reloadFB {

}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh
                               target:self
                               action:@selector(refreshChannels:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Menu" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(showMenu)];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandler:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

    self.myTableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];

     [self issueLoadRequest];
}

- (void)swipeHandler:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    [[self sideMenu] showFromPanGesture:sender];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Button actions

- (void)showMenu
{
    [[self sideMenu] show];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (void)issueLoadRequest
{
    if (changeData.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://my-site-facebookparse.php?person=Person"]];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(receiveData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
    } else {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://my-site-twitterparse.php?person=Person"]];
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(receiveData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
        });
    }
}

- (void)receiveData:(NSData *)data {
    if (changeData.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
    self.tweets = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
    } else {
        self.tweets1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
        [self.myTableView reloadData];
    }
}

- (void)receiveTwitter:(NSData *)data {
    // When we have the data, we serialize it into native cocoa objects. (The outermost element from twitter is
    // going to be an array. I JUST KNOW THIS. Reload the tableview once we have the data.
    self.tweets1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
    [self.myTableView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (changeData.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        return self.tweets.count;
    } else {
        return self.tweets1.count;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"FacebookPost";

    // The element in the array is going to be a dictionary. I JUST KNOW THIS. The key for the tweet is "text".
    NSDictionary *tweet = [self.tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSDictionary *tweet1 = [self.tweets1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    FacebookPost *cell = (FacebookPost *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FacebookPost" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    if (changeData.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
        cell.fbPost.text = [tweet objectForKey:@"message"];
    } else {
        cell.fbPost.text = [tweet1 objectForKey:@"tweet"];
    }
    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 90;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (changeData.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) {
    //Open the link
    int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
    NSString * storyLink = [[tweets objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey:@"message"];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:storyLink]];

    RNBlurModalView *modal = [[RNBlurModalView alloc] initWithViewController:self title:@"Message" message:storyLink];
    [modal show];

    NSString *formattedJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[self.tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"tweet:\n%@", formattedJSON);
    } else {
        //Öppna länken eller liknande
        int storyIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition: [indexPath length] - 1];
        NSString * storyLink = [[tweets objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey:@"tweet"];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:storyLink]];

        RNBlurModalView *modal = [[RNBlurModalView alloc] initWithViewController:self title:@"Message" message:storyLink];
        [modal show];

        // Spit out some pretty JSON for the tweet that was tapped. Neato.
        NSString *formattedJSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:[self.tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"tweet:\n%@", formattedJSON);
    }
}



@end
```

The table view data is downloading the Twitter post on the launch, even if I have set it to download the Facebook posts. It's very strange... Please help me fix this!

Comment: How are you setting the selected index of `changeData`? That's not included in the code above.

Comment: How do you mean? I'm setting if (changeData.selectedSegmentIndex == 1)  in numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath @neilco

Comment: To set the selected segment index, you will need something like this: `changeData.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;` in your code _before_ the call to `[self issueLoadRequest]`.

Comment: It's wierd beacuse when I set changeData.selectedSegmentIndex = 1; before [self issueLoadRequest] the selectedSegmentIndex is set to the second tab in the segmentcontrol... @neilco

Comment: That's correct. The segment index is zero-based, i.e. the first segment is index 0.

Comment: Yes, ok. Now it's correct. When I launch the app the first segment control view downloads data 1. But when I click on segment control 2 the table view is empty... Why? @neilco

Comment: That's because you're not listening for the `UIControlEventValueChanged` event on the UISegmentedControl. When this is called, you should call `[self issueLoadRequest]` to get the relevant data.

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry. I'm a beginner. So what should I add/remove? @neilco

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39282/discussion-between-neilco-and-david-gabor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things you need to do. Firstly, you need to set the selected segment index. Before you call `[self issueLoadRequest]` in `viewDidLoad`, you should set the selected index like this:

```
changeData.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
```

This will set the first segment to be the selected segment. Also, you'll need to make sure the correct data is loaded when you change the selected segment. To do that, you should add the following to `viewDidLoad`:

```
[changeData addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlSelectedIndexChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

And the companying method, `segmentedControlSelectedIndexChanged`:

```
- (void)segmentedControlSelectedIndexChanged:(id)sender 
{ 
    [self issueLoadRequest]; 
}
```

Now whenever you changed between the Facebook segment and the Twitter segment, it will call the corresponding API, download the data, and update the table view. Depending on the speed on your connection, there may be a small, but noticeable delay between selecting the segment and the table view updating.